# EF Core MySQL - Can't map DBnull values

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core

I have an issue that I can't seem to get around. I'm working with renewing an application based on an existing MySQL database. I'm using EF Core 6.0.1 and [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 6.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/).

I can easily retrieve data from tables so I know the setup is working. However - when I try to map an entity to a table containing a nullable value in MySql, EF Core throws an error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.
```

A short example could be this class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; };
}
```

Mapped to a table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
    `Id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Username` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Email` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`) USING BTREE
;
```

I have the following mapping in place:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Users");
    builder.HasKey(o => o.Id);
    builder.Property(t => t.Username).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(50);
    builder.Property(t => t.Email).HasColumnType("varchar");
}
```

In the current example the Username and Email fields can contain null values in the DB (and they do).
If I remove Username and Password from my class, then everything works. But whenever I have a nullable type I try to map, I get the DBnull exception.

I'm very new to using EF with MySQL - so I figure there might be something I'm missing? :)

Comment: Try to use nullable directive `string?`

Comment: Same as [this issue](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1571)?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I completely forgot about nullable reference types! After adding the string? to the type - everything came together. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @GertArnold - good link. I checked my csproj file just to be sure - but that link is definitely going to save some people some hassle :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments from @GertArnold and @SvyatoslavDanyliv below, I fixed my issue by doing the following:

1. Ensuring that my csproj file had `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`
2. Set my Username and Email properties to nullable reference types by using `string?` instead of just `string`

Solved everything right away.
Thanks guys.